# How to prevent false positive findings with repeated correlations?

Tags: correlation, multiple-comparisons

I have to run repeated correlations. If one of them reach the significant value (as given in the Pearson table), how can I be sure that it isn't actually a false positive?

I'm pretty new in the statistical analysis, so I apologize if my question seems naive.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: The answer depends (*strongly*) on whether these repeated correlations are independent.  In a common case you have a set of *m* related variables and you test all m(m-1)/2 mutual correlations, which obviously are not independent.

Answer (score 5):

I think  you should consider [Bonferroni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) correction. This seems a [multiple comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons) problem, so Bonferroni is only one of the solutions, but it is the easiest to implement.

Comment: Ok but i know that the Bonferroni is very conservative. As an exemple, if i'm doing 10 comparaisons, does that mean that for a p < .05 (for a single comparaison) i'll need to find a p < .05/10 on the 10 comparaisons?

Comment: Yes. You may try this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method. It is less conservative and at least in regression setting for me it gave reasonable results.

Comment: @Richard There's generally a trade-off between FPs and FNs in MCP, the Bonferroni's method being prone to increase FNs, while step-down methods (like the one suggested to you by @mpiktas) will perform better in most cases. As an alternative, you might want to look at permutation-based methods which offer a good compromise for the simultaneous control of FP and FN rates. @mpiktas (+1) In R, relevant methods are found in the base function `p.adjust()`, and the [multcomp](http://j.mp/eVflBe) and [multtest](http://j.mp/hirQrK) packages have great vignettes describing all of this.

Comment: First thanks to all of you for your answers. I think i'm going to try what @mpiktas suggested with the p.adjust() function and holm method in r.

Comment: I'm in the middle of sorting through this multiple testing as well, and in clicking on your links @chl, the multtest package in R has been removed. I can't comment on whether the multcomp will do what Richard did, but thought I'd let you know about multtest while I was thinking of it.

Comment: @Mog Yes, since then it has moved to BioC. Let us know if you encounter a problem with using them.